# Introducing dependency breaks existing dependency?

Tags: java, maven, junit, intellij-idea

I'm working on a project that builds and deploys fine.  I'm trying to add some code that uses JWebUnit, and use the following Maven code to bring it in:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jwebunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>jwebunit-htmlunit-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Maven seems to resolve this fine and it's bringing everything in (I'm using Intellij, and it now appears under 'Dependencies' in the 'Maven Projects' tab, and also under 'External Libraries' in the Project tab).

However, when I bring this dependency in, the IDE is not able to find it (e.g. if I use `import net.sourceforge.jwebunit.junit.WebTester`, it can't find it).

But an even bigger issue is it actually breaks some existing code -- I have some JUnit tests that use org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient, and now on Maven's install goal I get a
`NoClassDefFoundError - Could not initialize class` for that class.

If I remove the JWebUnit dependency, the Maven install goal exits successfully.

I'm used to seeing errors about dependency version convergence when bringing new dependencies, and I feel like chasing this 'no class def found' error could be a red herring, but I'm not sure of the general types of issues in Maven that could be causing it.

EDIT:  the dependency code for pulling in HttpClient is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jwebunit-htmlunit-plugin` includes transitive dependencies which seem like they're conflicting with some of your dependencies (likely because they are different versions).

Maven puts classpath priority on artifacts declared earlier.  Try moving `jwebunit` to the end of your dependencies section, or at least after where you pull in the `httpclient` classes. Alternatively, you can manually exclude certain transitive dependencies from being pulled in, but this can be tedious.

As for your IDE not allowing imports on the library, remember that you have this declared in the `test` scope.  Production classes cannot see `test` dependencies.

Comment: Good suggestion, as I've actually run into issues caused by the order of dependencies before; however, in this case, trying to place the new dependency at at the beginning (it was at the end to start) doesn't seem to help.

The project's pom structure is also very simple -- only one pom -- so there shouldn't be anything else being pulled in other than what is in this pom.

(unless it's possible that placing it somewhere between certain dependencies could help?)

Comment: @user3183922: Can you update your question to show the Maven GAV for httpclient?  For reference, jwebunit pulls in htmlunit which pulls in httpclient 4.3.2.

Comment: @user3183922: IntelliJ's Maven->Show Dependencies... is very useful there.  It shows you the tree of transitive dependencies and you can use CTRL-F to search for what you're looking for.

Comment: Updated question; luckily it was easy to identify.

Comment: So that gets difficult because you're actually looking at a major version difference...you can try excluding httpclient from your jwebunit-htmlunit-plugin, but it might not be compatible with 3.1.  At the end of the day, your tests are run with a simple classloader that goes on classpath priority.  It isn't like OSGi where you can have duplicate classes running sandboxed in their own classloaders.  The easiest thing for you honestly might be to update your code to httpclient 4.3.2.

Comment: Going with your suggestion, as there's only one class and its associated tests that use the 3.1 code.  I've almost got the main class converted and working so it may not be all that difficult after all...